One side stream call with WebRTC flutter
I'm currently adding video call to my app (FLutter for front-end and Asp.NET Core Web + SignalR for back-end) I'm using the flutter_webrtc library. No matter how hard i try i just succeed to make the client who initiate the call receiver the remote stream and the one who answer the call can't see the stream of the one who initiate the call
For now basically for someone who want to make a call i wiil click on a button on another page which will instantiate this page without the roomId and the process goes on in the setup function and at the end send a signal to the receiver through the hub.
For the one receiving, he will receiver a callback from another hub (to whom the app is always connected) that will push the PhoneCallPage with the roomId and he will have to press a button that trigger the answerCall function that will try to fetch the offer and so on
My flutter page :
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/components/appbar/gf_appbar.dart';
import 'package:scobius/runtime_data.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/signalr_client.dart';

class PhoneCallPage extends StatefulWidget{

  final String interlocutor;
  final String? roomId;

  const PhoneCallPage({required this.interlocutor, this.roomId, super.key});

  call(){
    
  }

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  State<PhoneCallPage> createState() => PhoneCallPageState(interlocutor, roomId);
}


class PhoneCallPageState extends State<PhoneCallPage>{
  String? interlocutor;
  String? roomId;
  bool callStart = false;
  bool isCaller = false;
  bool requestSended = false;
  PhoneCallPageState(this.interlocutor, this.roomId);

  HubConnection commHub = HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('${RuntimeData.serverBaseAddress}/call',
      options: HttpConnectionOptions(
        accessTokenFactory: () async => await Future.value(RuntimeData.sessionInformations?.token),
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
      ))
  .withAutomaticReconnect(retryDelays: [2000, 5000, 10000, 20000])
  .build();
  
  RTCPeerConnection? pc;

  final RTCVideoRenderer _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  final RTCVideoRenderer _remoteRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  MediaStream? localStream;
  MediaStream? remoteStream;

  late RTCSessionDescription _offer;
  

  final Map<String, dynamic> _configuration = {
    'iceServers': [
      {
        'urls': [
          'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
          'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
        ],
      },
    ],
  };


  @override
  void initState() {
    setup();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _localRenderer.dispose();
    _remoteRenderer.dispose();
    localStream!.dispose();
    remoteStream!.dispose();

    pc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setup() async{
    setState(() {
      isCaller = roomId == null;
    });
    await _localRenderer.initialize();
      await _remoteRenderer.initialize();

    await _initializeHubConnection();

    var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
        {'video': true, 'audio': true},
      );
    
    setState((){

      localStream = stream;
      _localRenderer.srcObject = localStream;
    });

    if(isCaller) await _createRoom(); 
  }

  Future<void> _initializeHubConnection() async{

    commHub.on('ReceiveOffer', _handleReceiveOffer);
    commHub.on('ReceiveAnswer', _handleReceiveAnswer);
    commHub.on('ReceiveIceCandidate', _handleReceiveIceCandidate);
    commHub.on('ReceiveIceCandidates', _handleReceiveIceCandidates);
    commHub.on('ReceiveRoomId', _handleReceiveRoomId);

    await commHub.start();
  }

  Future<void> _createRoom() async{
    pc = await createPeerConnection(_configuration);
    var offer = await pc?.createOffer();
    setState(() {
      _offer = offer!;
    });
    

    await commHub.invoke('CreateRoom', args : [offer!.sdp!]);
  }

  void _registerPeerConnectionListeners() {

    localStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) async{
      await pc?.addTrack(track, localStream!);
    });


    pc?.onIceCandidate = (candidate) async{
      await commHub.invoke('SendIceCandidate', args: [roomId! , candidate.toMap()]);
    };

    pc?.onAddStream = (stream) {
      remoteStream = stream;
    };

    pc?.onTrack = (event) {
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(
        (track) => remoteStream?.addTrack(track)
      );
    
    };
   
  }


  void answerCall() async{

    await commHub.invoke('GetOffer', args: [roomId!]);
  }

  void endCall() async{

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (localStream != null || _localRenderer.srcObject != localStream) {
      _localRenderer.srcObject = localStream!;
    }
    if (remoteStream != null || _remoteRenderer.srcObject != remoteStream) {
      _remoteRenderer.srcObject = remoteStream!;
    }
    

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GFAppBar(
        leading: Container(),
      
        title: Text(interlocutor!),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          (
          Expanded(
            child: callStart ? 
                    Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                            child: RTCVideoView(_remoteRenderer)
                          ),
                        Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 250,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
                            child: RTCVideoView(_localRenderer, objectFit: RTCVideoViewObjectFit.RTCVideoViewObjectFitContain,)
                          ),
                        
                      ])
                    : const Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white, 
                    radius: 50,
                    child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 40),
                  ),
            )
          )),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),

              child: callStart ? Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){}, 
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.video_call)
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){}, 
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.mic_off)
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: endCall, 
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.call_end,  color: Colors.red,)
                  ),
                ],
              ) : Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: answerCall, 
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.call)
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: endCall, 
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.call_end,  color: Colors.red,)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  

  void _handleReceiveRoomId(List<Object?>? arguments) async{
    roomId = arguments![0] as String;

    _registerPeerConnectionListeners();

    await pc?.setLocalDescription(_offer);
    
  }

  Future<void> _handleReceiveIceCandidate(List<Object?>? arguments) async {
    var candidate = arguments![0] as dynamic;

    await pc?.addCandidate(RTCIceCandidate(
      candidate['candidate'] as String,
      candidate['sdpMid'] as String,
      candidate['sdpMLineIndex'] as int,
    ));

    if(isCaller && !requestSended) {
      
      setState(() {
        requestSended = true;
      });
      await commHub.invoke('SendOffer', args: [interlocutor!,roomId!]);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleReceiveIceCandidates(List<Object?>? arguments) async {
    var candidates = arguments![0] as List<dynamic>;

    for (var candidate in candidates) {
      await pc?.addCandidate(RTCIceCandidate(
        candidate['candidate'] as String,
        candidate['sdpMid'] as String,
        candidate['sdpMLineIndex'] as int,
      )); 
    }
  }

  void _handleReceiveAnswer(List<Object?>? arguments) async{
    String sdp = arguments![0] as String;

    await pc?.setRemoteDescription(RTCSessionDescription(sdp, 'answer'));
    
    await commHub.invoke('GetIceCandiates', args: [roomId!]);
    setState(() {
      callStart = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleReceiveOffer(List<Object?>? arguments) async{
    String sdp = arguments![0] as String;

    pc = await createPeerConnection(_configuration);
    _registerPeerConnectionListeners();
    
    await pc?.setRemoteDescription(RTCSessionDescription(sdp, 'offer'));
    final answer = await pc?.createAnswer();
    await pc?.setLocalDescription(answer!);
    setState(() {
      callStart = true;
    });
    await commHub.invoke('GetIceCandiates', args: [roomId!]);
    await commHub.invoke('SendAnswer', args: [interlocutor!, answer!.sdp!]);
  }
}

And the SignalR hub that manage the communication :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Text.Json;
using ScobiusLibrary.DTOs;


namespace ScobiusServer.Hubs;

public class CommunicationHub(IHubContext<ServerHub> serverHub) : Hub
{

    public static List<CallRoom> CallRooms = new();

    public async Task CreateRoom(string sdp){
        string roomId = $"CallingRoom{CallRooms.Count}";
        CallRoom room = new CallRoom{
            RoomCreator = Context.UserIdentifier!,
            RoomId = roomId,
            Offer = sdp
        };

        CallRooms.Add(room);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(room));
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveRoomId", roomId);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
    }

    public async Task GetOffer(string roomId){
        var room = CallRooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomId == roomId);
        if(room == null) return;
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveOffer",  room.Offer, room.IceCandidates);
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, room.RoomId);
    }

    public async Task SendOffer(string receiverId, string roomId)
    {
        var room = CallRooms.First(r => r.RoomId == roomId);
        await serverHub.Clients.User(receiverId).SendAsync("ReceiveCallRequest", roomId, room.RoomCreator);
    }

    public async Task SendAnswer(string roomCreator, string answer)
    {
        await Clients.User(roomCreator).SendAsync("ReceiveAnswer", answer);
        
    }

#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
    public async Task SendIceCandidate(string roomId, IceCandidate candidate)
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
    {
        CallRoom room = CallRooms.First(r => r.RoomId == roomId);
        room.IceCandidates.Add(candidate);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(room));

        await Clients.Group(roomId).SendAsync("ReceiveIceCandidate", candidate);
    }

    public async Task GetIceCandiates(string roomId){
        CallRoom room = CallRooms.First(r => r.RoomId == roomId);
        var candidates = room.IceCandidates;
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveIceCandidates", candidates);
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        var room = CallRooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomCreator == Context.ConnectionId);
        if(room != null) CallRooms.Remove(room);
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}

I hope i have given enough informations. And by the way i use my phone and an emulator as devices
